# Drawing multiple oval shapes on HTML canvas using JavaScript having an extra line

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to know more about HTML canvas and JavaScript. Now I am trying to draw multiple oval shapes overlapping on each other and size will become smaller and smaller one after one. I can draw the shapes successfully.

This is my code

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var center_x = 200;
    var center_y = 100;
    var width = 100;
    var height = 200;
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 100, 200);
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 80, 180);
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 60, 160);
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 40, 140);
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 20, 120);

    function drawOvalShape(context, center_x, center_y, width, height){
        context.ellipse(center_x, center_y, width, height,  90 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

        context.stroke();
    }
</script>
```

When I run my code on the browser, it displays like this.

[image]

But the problem is why an extra line is included as below?

[image]

How can I get rid of that line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `context.beginPath`. Please see this JSFIddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zwcd7hcw/

```
function drawOvalShape(context, center_x, center_y, width, height){
        context.beginPath()
        context.ellipse(center_x, center_y, width, height,  90 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.stroke();
}
```

```js
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var center_x = 200;
    var center_y = 100;
    var width = 100;
    var height = 200;
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 100, 200);
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 80, 180);
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 60, 160);
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 40, 140);
    drawOvalShape(context, 200, 100, 20, 120);

    function drawOvalShape(context, center_x, center_y, width, height){
   context.beginPath()
        context.ellipse(center_x, center_y, width, height,  90 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

       context.stroke();
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```